# Binary search tree - max distance to a LEAF

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, binary-search-tree, computer-science

I need to write a linear algorithm that gets a BST and adds to every NODE a field with its max distance to a LEAF (if a NODE is a LEAF, the distance is zero).

I just need a pseudo code and the run time complexity.

Thanks,
Ofer.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/recursion.html

Comment: Show us your progress so far

Comment: did you have any success implementing your function? If the given answers were helpful, it is customary to upvote them or additionally mark the correct answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

The run time is the number of items in the tree.

```css
void addField(node n, int distance)
{
   if(n.left != null)
   {
      addField(n.left, distance + 1);
   }
   if(n.right != null)
   {
      addField(n.right, distance + 1);
   }
   if((n.right == null) && (n.right == null))
   {
      n.distance = distance;
   }
}​
```

Comment: This will compute the distance from the root. The OP wants the (max) distance to a/any leaf.

Answer (score 0):

This function works on balanced binary trees, needs some tweaks for unbalanced trees and stuff, but you should be able to work that out on your own.

It is called on the root node of the tree and will work recusively

```
struct Node(){
    int distance;
    Node* leftChild, rightChild;
    bool isLeaf(){ return rightChild==NULL && leftChild==NULL};
}

int dist(Node n){
     if(n.isLeaf()){
          n.distance = 0;
     }else{
          n.distance = 1 + max(dist(n.leftChild),dist(n.rightChild));
     }
     return n.distance;
}
```

Runtime complexity is linear, but it is not tail recursive. Therefore, the maximum number of nodes is limited by the depth of your stack.